# Retornar Valores mayor y menor Mediante Procedimientos almacenado del registro "masa"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Como puedo Retornar valores mayores y menores en registros de masa u edad

```
Create Table if not exists BDcmp5soP02.StudentGroup
(CvPerso int(4) Auto_Increment Primary Key comment "Clave consecutiva de los datos",
NumCtrl varchar(9) not null comment "Número de Control del alumno",
ApPater Varchar(20) not null comment "Apellido Paterno del alumno",
ApMater Varchar(20) not null comment "Apellido Materno del alumno",
Nombre Varchar(20) not null comment "Nombre del alumno",
Edad int(3) unsigned not null comment "Edad correspondiente del alumno",
Altura Float not null comment "Altura del alumno",
Masa int(3) unsigned not null comment "Masa corporal del alumno") 
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Insert Into BDcmp5soP02.StudentGroup (CvPerso, NumCtrl, ApPater, ApMater, Nombre, Edad, Altura, Masa) Values
(Null, '16700105', 'LOPEZ', 'FIGUEROA', 'ALEXIS BLADIMIR', 20, 1.70, 53),
(Null, '15700168', 'AGUILAR', 'AGUILAR', 'CARLOS JACOB', 23, 1.70, 65),
(Null, '16700129', 'VELAZQUEZ', 'ROBLERO', 'LUVIA', 21, 1.51, 51),
(Null, '15700191', 'GARCIA', 'HERNANDEZ', 'JOSE JOSE', 21, 1.56, 52),
(Null, '16700091', 'BAUTISTA', 'RAMIREZ', 'LUIS HUMBERTO', 20, 1.67, 52),
(Null, '16700452', 'VAZQUEZ', 'LUCAS', 'HUMBERTO', 20, 1.60, 57),
(Null, '16700119', 'RUIZ', 'AGUILAR', 'IRVING DARINEL', 20, 1.68, 52),
(Null, '16700111', 'PENAGOS', 'GORDILLO', 'LUIS ALBERTO', 20, 1.70, 75),
(Null, '16700122', 'SOLIS', 'AGUILAR', 'GERARDO DANIEL', 19, 1.75, 100),
(Null, '16700138', 'FLORES', 'PANTOJA', 'HUGO GILBERTO', 20, 1.70, 69);
```

delimiter $$
create procedure spMayMen2(
total int(4),
alumnos int(3)
)
begin
select max(Masa)as 'mayor Masa' from StudentGroup
where total=total;
select min(Edad)as 'menor Edad' from StudentGroup
where alumnos=alumnos;
end
$$
delimiter ;

```
---
```

delimiter $$
create procedure spMayMen2(
total int(4),
alumnos int(3)
)
begin
select max(Masa)as 'mayor Masa' from StudentGroup
where total=total;
select min(Edad)as 'menor Edad' from StudentGroup
where alumnos=alumnos;
end
$$
delimiter ;

```
gracias por la respuesta
```

Comment: Vale, pero donde esta el procedimiento y que fallo tiene ese procedimiento?

Comment: Nos falta informacion de que es lo que falla y un ejemplo..

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.